# React unmount and remount child component

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I have an npm imported component (CKEditor) that only cares about the state of its parent component at the time it mounts. I.e., no matter what changes occur in the state of the parent component, CKEditor won't reflect those changes if it has already mounted.

This is an issue for me because I need CKEditor to change based on the state of the parent component when the parent component changes its language prop.

Is there a way for me to make a child component unmount and mount again from the parent component? For example, is there a way for me to unmount and mount again a child component based on the parent component's "componentWillReceiveProps"?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import CKEditor from "react-ckeditor-component";

    export default class EditParagraph extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                // an object that has a different html string for each potential language
                content: this.props.specs.content,
            }
            this.handleRTEChange = this.handleRTEChange.bind(this)
            this.handleRTEBlur = this.handleRTEBlur.bind(this)
        }

        /**
         * Native React method 
         *  that runs every time the component is about to receive new props.
         */
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            const languageChanged = this.props.local.use_lang != nextProps.local.use_lang;
            if (languageChanged) {
                // how do I unmount the CKEditor and remount it ???
                console.log('use_lang changed');
            }
        }

        handleRTEChange(evt) {
            // keeps track of changes within the correct language section
        }

        handleRTEBlur() {
            // fully updates the specs only on Blur
        }

        getContent () {
            // gets content relative to current use language
        }

        render() {
            const content = this.getContent();

            // This is logging the content relative to the current language (as expected), 
            // but CKEditor doesn't show any changes when content changes.
            console.log('content:', content);

            // I need to find a way of unmounting and re-mounting CKEditor whenever use_lang changes.
            return (
                <div>
                    <CKEditor 
                        content={content} 
                        events={{
                            "blur": this.handleRTEBlur,
                            "change": this.handleRTEChange
                        }}
                    />
                </div>      
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since CKEditor only uses "content" prop when it mounts, I needed to re-render the component when the local.use_lang of the parent component changes.

CKEditor can be forced to re-render by giving it a `key` prop equal to the value that should force it to re-render:

```
<CKEditor key={this.props.local.use_lang} etc />
```

This way, whenever the language prop changes, React creates a new CKEditor.

Keep in mind that I made use of this solution because CKEditor is a foreign component library that I installed with npm. If it was my own code I was working with, I would just make changes to how the Editor uses its props. However, since I refuse to make changes to foreign library code, this is the solution that allowed me to force a re-render without having to touch the internals of the Editor code.

Comment: For instance with react-google-maps: `key={JSON.stringify(this.props.defaultCenter) + this.props.defaultZoom}`

Answer (score 0):

Its because there is no change detected, so therefore it will not call `render()` again, and thus will not make another call to `getContent()`.

What you can do is have the content be part of the state (which according to your constructor, already is), and check in `componentWillReceiveProps()` if the `use_lang` is updated. If so, then you can update the state there by calling `this.setState({...rest, content = getContent()};`.

And then your component `render()` function should look like this

```
<CKEditor 
    content={this.state.content} 
    events={{
        "blur": this.handleRTEBlur,
        "change": this.handleRTEChange
    }}
/>
```

(As an aside, by calling `setState()`, this will in turn trigger a call to `render()`, and if any changes were detected, the changes will be shown. But note that this is not actually 'remounting' the component, it is merely updating the view. In other words, `componentWillMount()` and `componentDidMount()` will not be called after updating the state in this situation. Instead, `componentWillUpdate()` and `componentDidUpdate()` will be called). [Read more about the component lifecycle here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: I've already attempted this. I made a simple case where there is an additional input field under the editor. They both would read off the value of "state.content" and the content would be a simple string (instead of a nested object). And, while the input field changes its view when writing inside the CKEditor, the inverse isn't true.

Comment: CKEditor is a module. A component that I did not build, but that I installed through npm. I do not think it is good practice to alter the code of a foreign component library, so I only wanted to find a solution that did not require me to add code to the CKEditor component.