# How can I unmount and remount a component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component and surrounded it with an error boundary.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
   <ChildComponent />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

It looks like this inside the `<ErrorBoundary />`:

```
export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    }

    componentDidCatch(err, info) {
        console.log('error is caught in the errorbound')
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.errorSwitch === this.props.errorSwitch) return;
        console.log('there was an error in the parent component')
        this.forceUpdate()
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children
    }
}
```

How can I force `this.props.children` (the child component) to 1) unmount, then 2) remount, again?

I'm not looking for how to re-render with new props, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186927/react-unmount-and-remount-child-component) answer shows how to do.  I specifically want to unmount and remount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return { componentVisible && this.props.children}` where componentVisible is a prop that is used as a toggle, ideally a boolean.